# $scope.$parent access changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have just upgrade from AngularJS 1.2.2 to 1.4.1 ... and my site stopped working. After a little debugging I found that the issue is I was trying to access:

```
$scope.$parent.data
```

In 1.2.2, this would include objects assigned to the scope of all parents, however, now in 1.4.1, I have to use:

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.data
```

Is there any way to access the variables of parents at any level, as in 1.2.1? Or does anyone have insights into etiquette here?

Comment: It seems like your scope got wrapped by 3 parents instead of 1 as before.
That's mean that your scope's parent is now has an isolate-scope means that it's not sharing his data from his parents.
A better solution for those issues is to use services, but I can't see your code so I'm kind of guessing.
I think that code could be help.

Comment: Hi, the code is much to big to post here, 500 lines. I will look into using a service...